# Is there a way to implement all material components and directives itself act as web compnents using createCustomElements?

Tags: angular, express, web-component, angular-material2, angular-universal

In my recent development project are in Angular 2+. That needs to finish up and move to Angular 2+ by replacing already implemented web elements using template basic HTML technologies.

The Angular 2+ project deals with building template HTML and CSS on single or multiple builds and bundled with a single file. It does not require all cases in my existing project. That means likely express server template engine renders 'ejs' files on the spot. It quickly renders and routing is handled in expressjs. Every change is applied in the template that reflects immediately. This requirement needs to implement from the customer point of view in Angular 2+ with SSR. SSR handles Angular 2+ routing and the template needs to be rendered by different HTML not only like from index.html (Web application has more templates like overview.html etc. in dashboard.html).

Need to implement Multiple customer-specific dashboard templates in Angular 2+. But I am stuck in how to manage different client-based templates of dashboards likewise Express ejs template.

Below features are want to include in my project:
I need suggestions on what can I use and how to handle it in the Angular 12.2.16.

I learned about the Angular 2+ Universal Express Engine. On this server-side rendering is more relatively useful for me. On other hand, All the templates use Angular 2+ directives, and Angular 2+ Material directives are used as web components.

I also learned about building web components in Angular 2+ using `@angular/elements`. Can I integrate All the Angular 2+ elements and Attribute directives as Web components?

```html
<!-- overview.html On www or ejs views folder --> 
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Choose a date</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-nav-list>
    <!-- <a mat-list-item > NavList </a> -->
    <mat-list-item> Pepper </mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item> Salt </mat-list-item>
    <mat-list-item> Paprika </mat-list-item>
  </mat-nav-list>

<mat-list>
 <mat-list-item> Pepper </mat-list-item>
 <mat-list-item> Salt </mat-list-item>
 <mat-list-item> Paprika </mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
```

```js
import { Inject, Injector, NgModule, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { MatList, MatListItem, MatListOption, MatNavList } from '@angular/material/list';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { MatDatepicker, MatDatepickerInput } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatFormField, MatLabel } from '@angular/material/form-field';

export function getBaseHref(platformLocation: PlatformLocation): string {
  return platformLocation.getBaseHrefFromDOM();
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({ appId: 'serverApp' }),
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useFactory: getBaseHref, deps: [PlatformLocation]}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [MatList, MatListItem, MatNavList, MatListOption, MatDatepicker, MatLabel, MatFormField]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) public platformId: any, private injector: Injector) {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(platformId)) {
      // const { createCustomElement } = require('@angular/elements');
      // you can use createCustomElement here
      const matList = createCustomElement(MatList, { injector: this.injector });
      customElements.define('mat-list', matList);
      const matListItem = createCustomElement(MatListItem, { injector: this.injector });
      customElements.define('mat-list-item', matListItem);
      const matListOption = createCustomElement(MatListOption, { injector: this.injector });
      customElements.define('mat-list-option', matListOption);
      const matNavList = createCustomElement(MatNavList, { injector: this.injector });
      customElements.define('mat-nav-list', matNavList);
      // const matDatepicker = createCustomElement(MatDatepicker, { injector: this.injector });
      // customElements.define('mat-date-picker', matDatepicker);
      // const matFormField = createCustomElement(MatFormField, { injector: this.injector });
      // customElements.define('mat-form-field', matFormField);
      // const matLabel = createCustomElement(MatLabel, { injector: this.injector });
      // customElements.define('mat-label', matLabel);
      // const matDatepickerToggle = createCustomElement(MatDatepickerInput, { injector: this.injector });
      // customElements.define('mat-datepicker-toggle', matDatepickerToggle);

      // const date_picker = createCustomElement(PPDatePickerComponent, { injector: this.injector });
      // customElements.define('dashboard-report', date_picker);
    }
  }
  ngDoBootstrap() { }  
}
```

### Output

[image]

I am optain the paritial desired output. I am able to templating `MatList, MatNavList` with help of angualr `createCustomElements`, that generated as webComponents. I am not able to derive `MatDatepicker` Components Directive and also Attribute Directive like `matSuffix, matLine`.

Is there a way to implement all material components and attribute directives itself act as web compnents using `createCustomElements` programatically?

The above template differs from one customer from others. Here Template in the sense of Layout design.

In customer 1 sites need overview layout 1 and customer 2 sites need overview layout 2. How I work with different layouts in same component template different customers?

Comment: Can you adjust your post you are writing Angular (Angular 2+) or AngularJS. Cause those are 2 different things. I am assuming its just Angular due to you want to Angular Elements.

Comment: It is correct Angular 2+ that I want to mention at that place. Thanks for the update

Comment: @HenrikBøgelundLavstsen Please check my revised question. It is clear what I want to do in my project.

Comment: yeah its way more clear. Now i dont truely understand why you would just do webcomponents for individual components. Instead I would just create a component containing all elements expencted to be used by the custom customer dashboards. And make it so you could just give the dashboard either a input model or have the dashboard do its own api requests. What i don't know about if those dashboards would be serverside rendered or you need to prerender them. I am guessing that is up to the express server.